# DynamoDB retrieve only attribute values

Tags: amazon-web-services, attributes, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table that has userId as the PK and a single attribute called userToken.

I have written a batchGet() function to return all the userTokens for specific userIds, however it returns it like this:

[ { userToken: '1234' },
   { userToken: '5678' } ]

I'd like it to just return the values since I already know what the attribute name will be:
['1234', '5678']

How would I go about doing so?

```
        const params = {
        RequestItems: {
            UserTokens: {
                Keys: userIds,
                AttributesToGet: [
                    'userToken'
                ]
        }
        }
    };

    db.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            console.log(data.Responses);
            sendNotifications(data.Responses);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DynamoDB always returns the attribute name and value.
You can easily filter this on the client side.

```
val = [  { userToken: '1234' }, { userToken: '5678' } ];
reducer = (accumulator, currentVal) => { 
    accumulator.push(currentVal.userToken);
    return accumulator;
 }

console.log(val.reduce(reducer, []));
```